# Tkinter: Remove 2 characters from the end of a index

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

This probably is a duplicate, but, I cannot find my answer anywhere. So currently, I'm building a simplistic replica of Markup.
A simple explanation of the editor is; there are 2 Text widgets, the top-one (`self.editor`) is the one you type on the bottom-one is (`self.disp`) the one where the output appears.
This code is for the search of italics. Which is marked with *|*Hello!*|*. What this following code does, is finds the *|*any text*|* (`regex_italic`) and the *...ext*|* (`regex_itlc_end`), and get the positions (ex. 1.0 and 1.13). But, this also gets the **|* so in the formatted copy of it (which removes the vertical bar and asterisk), there are 2 extra characters. So if you type `|*Hello*| World` instead of "*Hello* World" as your output you get "*Hello W*orld" (the W and space are formatted as italic).

```
        regex_italic = r'^[|]\*.+\*[|].*$'
        regex_itlc_end = r'\*[|].*$'
        italic = self.editor.search(regex_italic, "1.0", "end", count=count_var, regexp=True)
        print(italic)
        if italic != "":
            end_itlc = self.editor.search(regex_itlc_end, italic, "end", count=count_var, regexp=True)
            if end_itlc != "":
                print(end_itlc)
                #end_itlc = float(end_itlc)
                #end_itlc -= 0.2
                #end_itlc = str(end_itlc)
                self.editor.tag_configure('italic', font=("Consolas Italic", 12))
                self.disp.tag_configure('italic', font=("Consolas Italic", 12))
                self.editor.tag_add('italic', italic, end_itlc)
                self.disp.tag_add('italic', italic, end_itlc)
```

So in the commented section, I've written some basic code to convert `end_itlc` to float and remove 2 characters and then return it to a string. But, you can see the fatal flaw, it doesn't work on math, so when you remove "0.2" you could remove 2 chars, 20 chars, 200 chars... So once you reach 10 characters, you lose the italic styling.
So here's my question, **is there any way to remove 2 characters off the output of `end_itlc`?**
Thanks, -Sky. (Full code (to editor project): https://pastebin.com/skzUxnMN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text widget indexes aren't floating point numbers. They are strings of the form *line*.*character*, which is why converting them to floating point numbers and attempting to do math won't work.

Text widget identifiers accept modifiers. In your case you want `-2chars` (or `-2c`) added to your index to subtract two character positions from the base index. You can use the `index` method to convert an index with modifiers into just an index if you want to see the end result of the modifications.

```
end_itlc = self.editor.index("{}-2chars".format(end_itlc))
```